# d3.js visualization on android 2.3

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, cross-browser, d3.js

I know that the android browser for 2.3 does not support SVG, but I'd like to know whether I could convert a d3.js SVG Visualization to a canvas using [Canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) on clientside. Is the browser able to parse SVG elements at all, or would this transformation from SVG to Canvas need to happen server side? Thanks in advance!

```
// Grab data from server...

var btoken = window.location.search.split( 'bearer_token=')[1].split('&')[0]; 
var endpoint = "http://dcaps-staging.media.mit.edu:8080/api/reality_analysis_service/get_reality_analysis_data?document_key=radialData&bearer_token=" + btoken;
console.log(endpoint);
  d3.json(endpoint, function(json){
  console.log(json);

  var data = json.radialData.data;
  var csvdata; 
      csvdata = data;

    //var data


var output_ = '';
for( property in data) {
output_ += property +':' + data[property]+';';
}
console.log(output_);

  var meta = json.radialData.meta;
  var capitalMeta = [];
  for (i = 0; i < meta.length; i++){
      capitalMeta.push(capitaliseFirstLetter(meta[i]));
  }

console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )

//var width = 335,
  //  height = 340,
  var width = window.innerWidth - 5,
      height = window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight * .35),
    outerRadius = height / 2 - 10,
    innerRadius = 120;

var angle = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var radius = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, outerRadius]);

var z = d3.scale.category20();
var whiteColor = d3.rgb(255,255,255);
var redColor = d3.rgb(200,100,50);
var newColor = d3.rgb(100,100,100);
var pink = d3.rgb(238,98,226);

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("zero")//.offset(function(d) { return d.y0; })
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function(d, i) { return i; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value; });

var replaceY0 = 0;

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.layer; });

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed")
    .angle(function(d,i) { return angle(i); })
    .radius(function(d) { return radius(replaceY0 + d.y); });


var lowestValues = [];

// parse response for lowest values
for (i = 0; i < csvdata.length; i++){
  if (csvdata[i].layer == "averageLow"){
      lowestValues.push(csvdata[i].value);
  }
}

var area = d3.svg.area.radial()
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed")
    .angle(function(d, i) { return angle(i); })
    //.innerRadius(function(d) { return radius(replaceY0); })
    .innerRadius(function(d, i) {
        if (d.layer == "User"){ // Hardcoded check right now, might change later...data tag must have USER in it...
          return radius(d.y);
        }
        else{
        return radius(lowestValues[i]);
      }
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return radius(replaceY0 + d.y); });

var heightPadding = 20;
var widthPadding = 2;

var svg = d3.select("#radial_chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width / 2) + widthPadding) + "," + ((height / 2) + heightPadding) + ")");

//console.log("data : ", data);
//console.log("svg : ", svg);

var output_SVG = '';
for( property in svg[0][0]) {
output_SVG += property +':' + data[property]+';';
}
console.log(output_SVG);

  var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));

  // Hardcoded swap for User and Average High
  var swapper = layers[2];
  layers[2] = layers[1];
  layers[1] = swapper;


//  console.log("LAYERS : ",layers);
console.log(capitalMeta[0]);

  // Extend the domain slightly to match the range of [0, 2π].
  angle.domain([0, layers.length]);
  //radius.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { console.log("d.y0: ",d.y0); console.log("d.y: ",d.y); return d.y + replaceY0; })]);
  radius.domain([0, 10]);
  var x = svg.selectAll(".axis");
  alert(svg.toString());
  // create Axis
  svg.selectAll(".axis")
      .data(d3.range(angle.domain()[1]))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + angle(d) * 180 / Math.PI + ")"; })
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(radius.copy().range([-5, -outerRadius]))
      .ticks(5)
      .orient("left"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("y", 
        function (d) {
          if (window.innerWidth < 455){
            console.log("innerWidth less than 455: ",window.innerWidth);
            return -(window.innerHeight * .33);
          }
          else{
            console.log("innerWidth greater than 455: ",window.innerWidth);
            return -(window.innerHeight * .33);
          }
        })
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d, i) { return capitalMeta[i]; })
      .attr("style","font-size:12px;");

  svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
      .style("fill",
        function(d, i) 
        {
          if (i === 0){
            return whiteColor;
          }
          else if (i == 1){
            return z(i);
          }
          else
          return newColor; 
        })
      .style("opacity",.6)
      .style("stroke",function(d, i){
       if (i == 0)
        return whiteColor;
      else if (i == 2)
        return pink;
      else if (i == 1)
        return whiteColor;
      })
      .style("stroke-width",function(d, i){

       if (i == 1){
          return 0;
        }
        else if (i == 0)
          return 0;
        else
          return 7;
      });
alert('finished');



/*

 // Create the svg drawing canvas...
      var canvas = d3.select("#radial_chart")
        .append("svg:svg")
          .attr("width", 300)//canvasWidth)
          .attr("height", 75)//canvasHeight);
          .attr("id","legend");

legendOffset = 35;
  legendMarginLeft = 60;

var arrayOfTypes = ["User","Average High-Low"];

      // Plot the bullet circles...
      canvas.selectAll("circle")
        .data(arrayOfTypes).enter().append("svg:circle") // Append circle elements
          .attr("cx", legendMarginLeft)// barsWidthTotal + legendBulletOffset)
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return legendOffset + i*25; } )
          .attr("stroke-width", ".5")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) { 
          if (i == 0)
            return pink;
          else
            return z(i) }) // Bar fill color
          .attr("r", 10);

      // Create hyper linked text at right that acts as label key...
      canvas.selectAll("a.legend_link")
        .data(arrayOfTypes) // Instruct to bind dataSet to text elements
        .enter().append("svg:a") // Append legend elements
      .append("text")
              .attr("text-anchor", "left")
              .attr("x", legendMarginLeft+15)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) { return legendOffset + i*24 - 10; })
              .attr("dx", 5)
              .attr("dy", "1em") // Controls padding to place text above bars
              .text(function(d, i) { return arrayOfTypes[i];})
              .style("color","white")
*/

//                 canvg();
    alert('finished');


  });

function capitaliseFirstLetter(string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Android does support Canvas](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas), so that's certainly a good option (as far as SVG support goes, [you are right that Android 2.3 is not compatible](http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG)).

You can actually use canvas directly in d3; here is a comparison that Mike Bostock made showing the differences between using SVG and Canvas using a simple example:

[Canvas Swarm](http://bl.ocks.org/2647922) / [SVG Swarm](http://bl.ocks.org/2647924)

Keep in mind that you're not just limited to SVG or Canvas; for instance,  [www.nytimes.com/interactive](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl:nytimes.com/interactive) has been seen using d3.js with HTML elements for visualizing (I'm suspecting for better cross-browser support).
See: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/02/13/us/politics/2013-budget-proposal-graphic.html

Comment: I'm highly confused. I thought d3.js was built using only SVG??

Comment: Nope, "D3 solves the crux of the problem: efficient manipulation of documents based on data." (http://d3js.org/#introduction)

Comment: In other words, you can use HTML, SVG, Canvas; anything that belongs in a HTML document can be manipulated using D3.

Comment: you're the man. I'll let you know if I run into any issues but your examples are super helpful.

Comment: the page that I'm trying to port to Canvas is above. Would you be kind enough to take a quick look at this, and see what I need to do to port it over? the main questions I have are how to deal with things like d3.svg.axis(), or d3.svg.line.radial(). I tried substituting 'Canvas' for 'SVG' but that clearly was not the right way to do this...Thanks so much!

Comment: Better we carry this discussion over to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620621/d3-js-svg-to-canvas-conversion).

Comment: Yea I thought I needed to make a new question given that my last comment was sort of out of the scope of this one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you CAN use Canvg to display d3's SVG as canvas on the client side. Following the code in here: http://jsfiddle.net/plaliberte/HAXyd/ you just feed the div with the generated SVG to the Canvg function. The only catch is that if you use ".style" in part of your d3 operations it will throw an error for some reason. For example:

```
.style("text-anchor","middle")
```

In Android 2.x it throws:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'this.style' [null] is not an object
```

Therefore you will need to modify these methods to use .attr("style" instead:

```
.attr("style", "text-anchor:middle")
```

There are also functions inside d3 that use the style method like axis, so you may also need to make this substitution inside the library.