# D3.js svg to canvas conversion

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, cross-browser, d3.js

I'm trying to convert a d3.js visualization to canvas. The d3.js code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/3166265

Could somebody explain the basics of converting this visualization to canvas? I cannot use a program like canvg because the browser I'm targeting (android platform 2.3) cannot parse any SVG AT ALL. Therefore I need to convert this visualizatoin to Canvas. Any help that you can provide would be most appreciated...

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript? Do you know how to use d3?

Comment: neither as well as you. I picked up js and d3 about 2 or 3 weeks ago. If you can point me to a tutorial on how to do this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @wex currently trying to just do this server side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632748/svg-to-png-server-side-using-node-js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pushing D3.js output through fabric.js for IE8 support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817882/pushing-d3-js-output-through-fabric-js-for-ie8-support)

Comment: If you can't parse SVG I don't think you can get it into the canvas. Typical solutions look like this:     
    var svg = d3.select("#svgdiv").node().parentNode.innerHTML;
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function(){
     var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            //Explicitly setting the w/h seems to work better for me.
            canvas.width = this.width||960;
            canvas.height = this.height||500;
     canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0,0);
            //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
SVG is basically just XML, can you show as a string?