# in browser screenshots of nvd3 (or d3 with css)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

i'm running a rails app and trying to get a screenshot of an nvd3 graph in-browser.

from my testing, canvg and html2canvas can't render the css that accompanies nvd3. has anyone been able to create a png from an nvd3 svg?

html2canvas example - try rendering [the nvd3 scatter](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html) on [html2canvas preview](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html). it's not working...

any ideas?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632748/svg-to-png-server-side-using-node-js) should help if you can do it on the server.

Comment: Further reading, [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) page from phantomJS wiki and [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Related-Projects#screenshot-utilities) collection of screen grab utilities might help.

Comment: isn't phantomJS a terminal utility? how would i use it in-browser?

Answer (score 0):

from the html2canvas [FAQ](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html) we know that it cannot properly deal with svg.

i have very similar requirement and "[example of how to export a png directly from an svg](http://bl.ocks.org/deanmalmgren/22d76b9c1f487ad1dde6)" solved my problem (internally it adopted [svg-crowbar](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) code). basically, you need to draw the svg to a canvas then export the image to png, and "explicitly set css style" for all svg element is the caveat to make the exported image like original.