# Javascript chart or graph generation via browser or node server only for existing public solutions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I'm working on adapting existing solutions for my use in the meantime, but was curious to know if chart/graph library solutions for javascript are used only either from browser/web apps or via node.js but server side (via HTTP/REST requests).

For the node case, do most people not have a need or not prefer to have a pure CLI server-less implementation like a CLI tool/script?

Maybe I haven't searched enough, looking for not web-based javascript charting/graphing, I came across these:

https://github.com/ubear/hegel

https://github.com/Objectway/d3-server-renderer

but they expose an HTTP/REST server one needs to query to generate the graph outside of a browser. That's halfway there, and I'm currently trying to adapt those.

Is there not any similar solution that just spits out a chart/graph based on stdin or a (CSV) file you pass to it as a command line argument to a node script? The overhead of HTTP/REST seems unnecessary in cases that don't need distributed computing or scalability, like a local/internal deployment.

Comment: You can use D3 on the server, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632748/svg-to-png-server-side-using-node-js

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for server side graph/plotting to a static format like PNG or SVG?

I use [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for such tasks. For [example](https://github.com/kaihendry/sg/blob/master/plotters/gnuplot.sh).